# How to do WordPress Admin Tour Popups?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, popup, admin

I'm not one for posting a "how do you do this?" without posting some code or an attempt - but I can't find a tutorial anywhere! I don't even know where to start.

When WordPress upgrades, or even some plugins like SEO by Yoast, they give these wonderful little **"guided tour" tabs**. I've done some searches on a tutorial for this, but I suspect I'm not even naming them properly to show any Google results!

Simply stated, what methods are responsible for making Admin popups such as the ones mentioned above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are **Admin Pointers**.
I'm not finding documentation in the Codex, but here some tutorials from good sources:

- [Integrating With WordPress’ UI: Admin Pointers](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/integrating-with-wordpress-ui-admin-pointers/)
- [Introduce Your Plugin With WordPress Pointers](http://www.paulund.co.uk/introduce-wordpress-pointers)
- [How to Add and Deactivate the new Feature Pointer in WordPress 3.3](http://wpengineer.com/2272/how-to-add-and-deactivate-the-new-feature-pointer-in-wordpress-3-3/)

and [related posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=admin%20pointer) at WordPress Answers.